# Conjugación después del relativo "quien"/"el que"

Tags: gramática, conjugación

Tengo una pregunta sobre relativos, y creo que lo mejor es empezar por el ejemplo.

De forma natural, yo construyo las siguientes frases así:

> - Soy yo quien/el que **tiene** razón.
> - Eres tú quien/el que **tiene** razón.
> - Es él quien/el que **tiene** razón.
> - Somos nosotros quienes/los que **tenemos** razón.
> - Sois vosotros quienes/los que **tenéis** razón.
> - Son ellos quienes/los que **tienen** razón.

Si os fijáis, en las tres primeras frases, que corresponden a las personas en singular, el verbo después de "quien"/"el que"/"los que" está conjugado en 3ª del singular.

Sin embargo, para las personas en plurar, el verbo se conjuga en concordancia con el sujeto de la principal (nosotros/vosotros/ellos).

Me di cuenta de esto en una clase de francés, ya que en la estructura equivalente del francés, el verbo de la subordinada siempre va en concordancia con el de la principal. Digamos que en francés sería:

> - *Soy yo quien/el que tengo razón* *.

Frase que a mí me suena horrible. Sin embargo, no estoy tan segura de que para el plural sea correcta la forma que pongo en los ejemplos: buscando en Google las frases "somos nosotros quienes tenemos" y "somos nosotros quienes tienen", obtenemos un número muy similar de resultados.

Así pues, las preguntas: ¿es esto correcto? ¿Está esto reglado o recogido en algún sitio? ¿Por qué sucede? ¿Es un fenómeno regional o es global en todo el castellano?

En la RAE, no encuentro [información al respecto](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=QdP8Fv3omD69crIpsn).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En el DPD hay una entrada sobre concordacia de verbos y en [último punto](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XEVeLzVZaD6CG25cW5#413) habla justamente de eso.

Para el singular:

> Si el sujeto del verbo *ser* es un pronombre de primera o de segunda
>   persona del singular (yo, tú/vos), el verbo de la oración de relativo
>   puede ir, bien en tercera persona del singular, en concordancia
>   estricta con su sujeto gramatical (el/la que o quien), opción
>   mayoritaria en el habla culta: *«Yo soy el que manda acá»* (Soriano
>   León [Arg. 1986]); bien en primera o segunda persona del singular,
>   concordando con el sujeto del verbo ser, opción habitual en el habla
>   coloquial y que expresa mayor implicación afectiva por parte del
>   hablante: *«Por primera vez en mi vida yo soy la que tengo el
>   control»* (Santiago Sueño [P. Rico 1996]).

Para el plural:

> Cuando el sujeto de *ser* es un pronombre de primera o segunda persona
>   del plural (*nosotros, vosotros*), el verbo de la oración de relativo no
>   va nunca en tercera persona, sino que la concordancia se establece
>   siempre con el pronombre personal: *«Nosotros somos los que mandamos»*
>   (Chase *Pavo* [C. Rica 1996]).

Comment: Gracias @blonfu!! Me fascina que en singular se admitan las dos formas, prefiriéndose la conjugación en 3ª, pero en plural sólo se pueda usar la forma correspondiente a cada persona. ¡Justo al contrario de lo que pensábamos!

Comment: ¿Habrá también diferencias regionales? A este lado del Atlántico me suena perfectamente válido y normal decir _Soy yo el que **tengo** (la) razón_ pero para usar _quien_ solo me suena bien _Soy yo quien **tiene** (la) razón_